# How to edit windows installation disk (remove some drivers files)?

Tags: windows-7, installation, graphics-card

I have a no-name graphic card and when I try to install any version of windows; my system will be restarted. 
Finally I could boot the windows server 2003 and I noticed, it isn't recognize my graphic as default(in the Advance setting showed "Unavailabe"); and when I installed my graphic driver it was restarted again :(

Actually the standard VGA or unknown VGA is enough for me, but I want to install windows 7 now!!!

so Is there any way to delete auto detection graphic cards in windows 7 **installation process** or I have to delete built-in graphic drivers files, from the installation disk ??!
If I have to how?

Comment: If it gets as far as booting, have you tried safe mode?

Comment: yes but it just work at win server 2003 :( and I can't install the other version of windows because of detecting installation process!!!

Answer (score 0):

I was using [nLite](http://www.nliteos.com/guide/before.html) to do this in the past.
You can give it a try as well.

Comment: thnx but which files I have to delete?

Comment: nlite doesn't work with anything older than XP actually

Comment: there was a function in scripted installs to ignore the grafics. never had such problems, it is really odd if your getting a full on crash or something. The desciption of the actual problem your having i dont completly understand.  I would disable or pull the card temporarily.  it would beat trying to script something.

Comment: ok do you have it please?(the script) :)

Comment: Scripting installs is a whole world of work. Search for the WAIK thing. (I would rather go back to XP than to fight a older system win 7, especially after reading all the unfixed user frustrations in 7 at MStech)